# How to get the invoke arguments for an Adobe Air iOS app?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, invoke

I would like to get the invoke arguments (e.g. a path to a file) from the [Adobe Air Invoke Event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/InvokeEvent.html) for an Air for iOS app.
I tried the code below but the `onAppInvoke` function isn't fired after the app got launched.

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onAppInvoke);  
  
function onAppInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void {  
trace("INVOKE ARGS: "+event.arguments[0]);  
}
```

How to get the `event arguments` after the app got launched?
I'm using the latest Air SDK 16 and tested the app on iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an AIR application is invoked, AIR dispatches an InvokeEvent object of type invoke through the singleton NativeApplication object. To allow an application time to initialize itself and register an event listener, invoke events are queued instead of discarded. As soon as a listener is registered, all the queued events are delivered.

**Note**: When an application is invoked using the browser invocation feature, the NativeApplication object only dispatches an invoke event if the application is not already running.
To receive invoke events, call the addEventListener() method of the NativeApplication object (NativeApplication.nativeApplication). When an event listener registers for an invoke event, it also receives all invoke events that occurred before the registration. Queued invoke events are dispatched one at a time on a short interval after the call to addEventListener() returns. If a new invoke event occurs during this process, it may be dispatched before one or more of the queued events. This event queuing allows you to handle any invoke events that have occurred before your initialization code executes. Keep in mind that if you add an event listener later in execution (after application initialization), it will still receive all invoke events that have occurred since the application started.

Only one instance of an AIR application is started. When an already running application is invoked again, AIR dispatches a new invoke event to the running instance. It is the responsibility of an AIR application to respond to an invoke event and take the appropriate action (such as opening a new document window).

An InvokeEvent object contains any arguments passed to the application, as well as the directory from which the application has been invoked. If the application was invoked because of a file-type association, then the full path to the file is included in the command line arguments. Likewise, if the application was invoked because of an application update, the full path to the update AIR file is provided.

When multiple files are opened in one operation a single InvokeEvent object is dispatched on Mac OS X. Each file is included in the arguments array. On Windows and Linux, a separate InvokeEvent object is dispatched for each file.

Your application can handle invoke events by registering a listener with its NativeApplication object:

```
  NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvokeEvent); 

  var arguments:Array; 
  var currentDir:File; 

  public function onInvokeEvent(invocation:InvokeEvent):void { 
      arguments = invocation.arguments; 
      currentDir = invocation.currentDirectory; 
  }
```